# Is there a way to find sum of numbers to a certain power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

Suppose I have 4 numbers, for example (0, 2, 3, 5) and I square them ie (0, 4, 9, 25) and then sum them (38).  Is there a formula for determining what the sum would be if these numbers were raised to the 4th power? How about the 6th or 8th power?

Is there a general function for raising numbers to the nth power then summing?

Comment: Just go way back half a millennium ago: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Do you want a sum for $1+2^k+3^k+4^k+...$ or for the sum of the $k$-th powers of the elements of some arbitary set ?

Comment: Peter - an arbitrary set.  Not a sequence like 1,2,3,4,etc.

Comment: Then, the only possibility is to simply calculate the sum.

Answer (score 0):

$a^{n} + b^{n} + c^{n} + d^{n} $ is as general as you're going to get, and should be fairly simple to calculate (at least for low-ish powers).